GND plane on both sides?
I'm making a 2 layer pcb and I was wondering if I should have ground plane on both sides of the board or only on the bottom side. Is there any downsides of having gnd on both sides? And is it ok to have a ground pour even below the buck converter part - especially below the inductor? Here is my pcb layout:

GND only on the bottom side



GND on both sides




I'd be more worried about running the data lines to ethernet IC so tight together because of crosstalk and so on (especially with no series resistors). Also the RS485 lines should have a ground connection.

Both your ground planes are heavily compromised due to all the long traces. I would try to do via stitching between them to make the sum of both as complete as possible. Connect every island with at least one via. Or move to four layers.

@WesleyLee I will try to make a bigger space between them. Is the gnd connection needed if i will be using the same power supply for all the connected slaves?

@winny ok I added vias all over the board and made a little bigger spaces between the traces from the ethernet IC to the ESP32(updated pictures in the first post). Is it better now? And what about the GND pour under the inductor in the buck converter layout, is it ok?

I'm making a 2 layer pcb What's the thickness? Also, is the RJ1 to the top-left for ethernet?

@RohatKılıç The thickness is 1.6mm, and yes it's for ethernet.

Apparently, your design doesn't meet the impedance requirements. For a 1.6mm-thick PCB, the trace width should be nearly 1 mm (neglecting the trace-to-trace spacing for now but should be 0.2~0.3 mm depending on your PCB mfg's manufacturing capabilities) to get 100-Ohm differential impedance which is crucial for ethernet. So maybe you should focus on this first.

Yes, but you need to focus on all islands and panhandles. There are several still virtually or actually unconnected.

@k0cka You have far more serious issues now than worrying about ground pours. If you have 2 layer board it is unlikely you have the Ethernet impedances correct. And if those three buses are CAN or RS-485, please understand that they are not 2 wire buses, they have 2 data wires and require a third common ground wire between devices too. What is the device supposed to do?

@RohatKılıç I'm sorry, I'm not sure which traces are you talking about. It's my first pcb design with ethernet and rs485 so I'm in a new territory.

@Justme yeah I wasn't paying attention to impedances, I'm new to ethernet design and also rs485 so it's a little too much information for me :D I will try to study more about it because I have no clue what impedances are and why are they important. And about the rs485, my plan is to power all the modules on the buses from the same power supply so I thought that I don't need an extra GND wire between the modules. I would like to control some relay modules etc. with this.

Look up "PCB characteristic impedance". You need 100 ohm. There are simulators and examples available for various stackups and PCB thicknesses. Ethernet is possible on 2 layers, but with drawbacks to get to said 100 ohm.

@k0cka There are RX and TX pairs between the RJ1 and the ethernet magnetics (TR1), and there are another set of RX and TX pairs between the eth magnetics and the eth phy IC (U1, if my eyes don't wrong me). Do some research about  characteristic impedance and impedance mismatch. You can use online calculators for the trace width and trace-to-trace spacing for ethernet (100 Ohms differential impedance). You'll see that for a 1.6mm FR4 the trace width should be ~1mm for 0.3mm trace spacing. Better to use a 4-layer board with signal-ground-power-signal stack-up. The cost is pretty much the same.

it might be possible for a really experienced designer to make a 2 layer board work with ethernet, but yoi are not that. Make it possible fir yourself, use 4 layers (practically the same price board), make one of them an unbroken ground, and reference your controlled impedance traces to that.

@Neil_UK So with the 4 layer board I would have the top and bottom layer as it is but without the ground plane, and the 2 inner layers would be grounds? One of them just for the ethernet part and the second ground layer for the rest of the board? Do I understand correctly?

@Neil_UK Hahaha, no -- you forget just how slow Ethernet really is. Even Gigabit is one of the slowest among "high speed" interfaces in common use today. With pulse width on the order of 10ns, quite long stub/mismatch length is tolerable. This design would most likely work (in the sense of basic expected function). It wouldn't meet maximum distance requirements or etc., and more to the point, it wouldn't meet media isolation requirements. But you have to be actively malicious in design to defeat 100BASE-T Ethernet. And even then, it may still enumerate at 10Mbit!

Early in my career I made a 2 layer board - keep down the BOM cost, right? It worked, mostly. It had a handshake with the backplane, and every 12 or so hours, it would lock up and crash. Couldn't see what was going despite a battery of logic analysers, storage scopes, etc. Eventually we got a real pro in, and his main suggestion was to make a 4 layer board - we did that, and it ran fine forever. Save yourself the pain.

Two-layer is fine.  Actually, that's not bad.
The main things to beware of are:

Ethernet: treat the media side as hazardous voltage. It seems innocent enough, just an isolated cable, right? But it's rated up to 1.5kV isolation, so you need to be sure that isn't jumping to your circuit.  Remove ground here, under the transformer until the connector.  (It's fine to have ground up alongside, to meet the LED traces, and connector shell.)  This area should be poured underneath with the common node (Bob Smith termination) instead, with adequate separation distance (a few mm) to circuit GND, and then the ESD capacitor (1nF 2kV) goes from this node to circuit GND (or preferably, to chassis if present).
You'll want to read up on Ethernet layout appnotes and what "Bob Smith termination" is, to get a better idea what to do here.

As much as possible, all components and signals should have contiguous ground above or below them.  Intersections are inevitable, and routing a trace under another, necessarily creates a negative space where there is zero ground present on any layers.  Stitch around such openings, to minimize the open loop area, and perimeter, of this negative space.
Automatic via stitching placement is a start, but I've highlighted some priority locations below (green circles). Notice they target either side of relatively long traces, and islands/peninsulas where ground is otherwise poorly connected.



I've also roughly sketched how better to handle the Ethernet situation: it's probably easier to route the second pair up and around the pins; this will swap the pair polarity, but this is okay, swap it on the PHY side of the transformer as well.  And now that's also easier to connect.  Matter of fact, I think both are better this way.
Don't worry about length matching: they could be off by some cm and it won't really matter.  Since you don't have matched impedance, your priority is on keeping trace length short.  This arrangement allows you to butt the transformer and connector together (isolation distance permitting), and likewise transformer and PHY.
Impedance matching is impractical on 2-layer boards, maybe unless it's ordered very thin (<1mm): required trace width for 50Ω is about half the board thickness, or 0.8mm, a ponderous size for signal routing.  Just keep them short, so your too-thin traces look like small inductors -- small enough not to affect signal quality.  (Traces can still be fattened a bit, where it's practical to do so.)
You may also want to bus more strongly, the signals from left side of ESP32 to CN1, and route them below the right side of ESP32.  This avoids the column of vias shown above, so that just a quartet will stitch the bus crossing, and a few here and there can fill out the flat (GND over GND) areas, or their perimeters/corners.  This allows GND to pour under the ESP32 right-side pins.
Alternately, you could push all these traces to the top layer, and use short jumper lengths (which can be seen elsewhere on the board) so that bottom GND pours around most of them.  Those two right-side traces (in the gap between ESP32 and CN1) might be bottom-side then, with ground stitching.
What's D4 doing? Is that in case CN1 backpowers the unit, and POWER_IN is unavailable?  Hmm.  Depending on type, U6 might be okay with that, but maybe better not to risk it.  A wired-OR switch might be used, or maybe you can just improve things as-is: take feedback after D4 (I think that one via between C4/C7 is going back to U6-1?), and probably move C6/C7 after D4 so the regulator compensation isn't quite as weird as it would be otherwise.  Then the regulator compensates for D4's drop.

Thank you very much for your effort and detailed answer, I really aprreciate it! I will try to implement your points and come back with an updated layout. Btw while I was searching for some ethernet layouts, I run into this project which uses HR911105A with built-in magnetics. I think this would make things easier for me, what do you think? https://github.com/c-/ESP32-Ethgate

Yes, integrated magnetics jacks are convenient, saves board/layout area too.


There are no problems in having a ground plane on both sides of a two-layer PCB. If you are using many layers, there are some conventional PCB stack-ups that you could have a look at. (Knowing PCB stack up is helpful when designing multiple types of circuits. Have a look around Google)

Regarding the ground pouring under the inductor, I am quoting the following "It’s fair to conclude that placing ground below the switching node and inductor in a switching regulator PCB layout is not problematic if you’re willing to sacrifice a bit of inductance due to the presence of eddy currents in the adjacent copper. " Refer to the following link for a detailed explanation.


https://resources.altium.com/p/should-ground-be-placed-below-inductors-switching-regulators
